# Needing powershell help exporting 4 sections of data

Tags: csv, powershell

The following list compares a list of names to our AD here at my job. However, each section lists a lot of names and causes me not to be able to scroll up. I have tried using .\ylaudit2.ps1 | out-file workdayaudit1.csv and it just gives me a blank csv file. Can anyone assist me please?

```
$script:YLUserCSV = Import-CSV "c:\ylusers.csv"
$result = Test-Path "c:\\ylusers.csv"
    if($result -eq $FALSE){
    Write-Host "Path to CSV does not exist: \\$env:computername\c$\ylusers.csv"
    break
}
}

Function Analyze-UserAuthentication{

foreach ($row in $script:YLUserCSV){
    write-host "$row.username" 
    if ($row.authenticationtype -eq "LDAP"){
        $script:LDAPUsers += $row.username
    }
    elseif ($row.authenticationtype -eq "DATABASE"){
        $script:DBUsers += $row.username
    }
}
}

Function Check-DBUsers {
Write-Host "`nChecking accounts that use database authentication..." -     ForegroundColor Yellow
$DBUsersInAD = @("`n")

foreach ($user in $script:DBUsers){
    $DBUserCheck = Get-QADUser $user
    if ($DBUserCheck -eq $NULL){
        Write-Host "No Active Directory user $user found."
    }
    elseif ($DBUserCheck -ne $NULL){
        $DBUsersInAD += $DBUserCheck.Name+"`n"
    }
    else {
        out-null
    }
}
    Write-Host "`nDatabase authenticated Yodle Live users associated with AD accounts:" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host $DBUsersInAD | FL
}

Function Check-LDAPUsers {
Write-Host "`nChecking accounts that use LDAP authentication...-ForegroundColor Yellow
$LDAPUsersinAD = @("`n")
$inADandEnabled = @("`n")
$inADandDisabled = @("`n")
$notinAD = @("`n")

foreach ($user in $script:LDAPUsers){
    $LDAPUserCheck = Get-QADUser $user
    if ($LDAPUserCheck -ne $NULL){
        $LDAPUsersinAD += $LDAPUserCheck.Name+"`n"
        if ($LDAPUserCheck.AccountIsDisabled -ne $TRUE){
            $inADandEnabled += $LDAPUserCheck.Name+"`n"
        }
        elseif ($LDAPUserCheck.AccountIsDisabled -eq $TRUE){
            $inADandDisabled += $LDAPUserCheck.Name+"`n"
        }
    }
    else {
        $notinAD += $user+"`n"
        $LDAPUserCheck = $NULL
    }
}
Write-Host "`nEnabled Yodle Live accounts associated with disabled AD Users:" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host $inADandDisabled | FL
Write-Host "`nEnabled Yodle Live accounts not associated with any AD User:" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host $notinAD | FL
}
Set-ScriptVars
Import-UserData
Analyze-UserAuthentication
Check-DBUsers
Check-LDAPUsers
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't save the output is because you're using `Write-Host`. `Write-Host` only writes text to the interactive console, ex. status messages and such.

If you need to be able to save the output to a file, you need remove `Write-Host` (or use `Write-Output`) on the lines outputing the data  you want to save, so the objects will be passed down the pipeline so `| Out-File` can catch and save them.

Ex. replace:

```
Write-Host "`nDatabase authenticated Yodle Live users associated with AD accounts:" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host $DBUsersInAD | FL

#lots of code....
#...

Write-Host "`nEnabled Yodle Live accounts associated with disabled AD Users:" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host $inADandDisabled | FL
Write-Host "`nEnabled Yodle Live accounts not associated with any AD User:" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host $notinAD | FL
```

With:

```
"Database authenticated Yodle Live users associated with AD accounts:"
$DBUsersInAD

#lots of code....
#...

"Enabled Yodle Live accounts associated with disabled AD Users:"
$inADandDisabled
"Enabled Yodle Live accounts not associated with any AD User:"
$notinAD
```